# How to show Percentage sign in pie chart using daniel gindi/Chart library in swift(IOS Chart)

Tags: ios, swift, pie-chart

I am using the Charts framework (by Daniel gindi). It was working fine but 
how to show % (sign) on piechart? 
I am also try use NSNumberFormatter() method for covert data value in percantage but not get % sign.
I am upload code here

```
    @IBOutlet var pieChart: PieChartView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            var data = [25.0,37.5,12.5,12.5,12.5] // pie chart data 
            var status = ["A","B","C","D","E"] // status
            setChart(status, values: data)
            self.pieChart.drawSliceTextEnabled = false

    }
    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

            pieChart.noDataText = "you need to provide data for chart"
            pieChart.noDataTextDescription = ""
            self.pieChart.descriptionText = ""

            var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
            //pieChart.centerText = " "
            for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {

                let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
                dataEntries.append(dataEntry)

            }

            let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "")

            var colors: [UIColor] = []


            for _ in 0..<dataPoints.count {
                let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
                let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
                let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))

                let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
                colors.append(color)

                pieChartDataSet.colors = colors

            }

            let pieChartData = PieChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: pieChartDataSet)

            pieChart.data = pieChartData
            pieChart.animate(yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .EaseInOutBack)
}
```

---

## **Output:=>**

[image]

Comment: I guess that `PercentFormatter`, `YAxisValueFormatter` or `XAxisValueFormatter` may be a hint...

Comment: Is your problem resolved? then close this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To show % sign on pieChart.**

**[Download Example Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Tt25e1kQh9YmItTG8xR19pdkE/view?usp=sharing)**

Just use this below code.

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .PercentStyle
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
formatter.multiplier = 1.0
pieChartData.dataSet?.valueFormatter = formatter
```

You will get % sign after your value display on slice.

[image]

**Source** https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: Method use pieChartDataSet.valueFormatter = formatter instead of pieChartData.dataSet?.valueFormatter = formatter than get % sign

Comment: I have values like [6, 5, 3, 12], if I use above code with `multiplier = 10`, it showing as 60%, 50%, 30%, 120%, with `multiplier = 1` the percentages are 6%, 5%, 3%, 12%. But, I need to calculate percentage to 100 based on values provided. So, I need to give percentage value myself. Can you help me for that

Answer (score 11):

On `Swift3` with latest version of [charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) you can do `%` formatting on pie chart as followings:

```
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .percent
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    formatter.multiplier = 1.0
    pieChartData.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter:formatter))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) 4.1.0

Once assign the data to the chart view, set the value formatter. It works for me.

```
chartView.data = pieChartData

let format = NumberFormatter()
format.maximumFractionDigits = 1
format.numberStyle = .percent
format.multiplier = 1.0
let formatter = DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: format)
pieChartData.setValueFormatter(formatter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add these line to format the percentage in **PieChart**.

```
     let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
                        formatter.numberStyle = .PercentStyle
                        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
                        formatter.multiplier = 1.0
                        pieChartData.setValueFormatter(formatter)
// text color of percentage label
    slcCell.pieChartView.data?.setValueTextColor(UIColor.clearColor())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .percent
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    formatter.multiplier = 1.0
    chart.data?.setValueFormatter(formatter as? IValueFormatter)
```