# swift/charts: chart value int instead of double

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I want to turn the 1.00 and 2.00 into 1 and 2. When I try to change `entry.y = Double(value)` to `entry.y = Int(value)` it says it has to be a Double. How do I turn the values into whole numbers?

```
var entries = [PieChartDataEntry]()
        for (index, value) in dataarray.enumerated() {
            let entry = PieChartDataEntry()
            entry.y = Double(value)
            entry.label = self.labels[index]
            entries.append(entry)
        }
```

This is the chart I am using:

[image: Chart]

Comment: I have no experience with PieChart, but this looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453604/how-to-add-to-data-in-ios-chart, i.e. you have to set a "value formatter".

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the link but my data entry is structured differently than  the one in that post.

Comment: It was just meant as a hint that you look for "value formatters".

Answer (score 7):

```
let  pieChartView = PieChartView(frame:CGRect(x:60,y:50,width:200,height:300))

let track = ["Passed", "Failed", "Pending"]
let money = [10, 6, 10]

var entries = [PieChartDataEntry]()
   for (index, value) in money.enumerated() {
      let entry = PieChartDataEntry()

      entry.y = Double(value)     
      entry.label = track[index]
      entries.append( entry)
   }

let set = PieChartDataSet( values: entries, label: "")
let data = PieChartData(dataSet: set)

pieChartView.data = data

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
data.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter:formatter))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
entry.y = Double(value)
```

Do:

```
entry.y = Int(value)
```

Note that `2.1`, `2.2` etc will return `2`

Comment: I get the error of 'cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'Double''. It then suggests me to change it to `entry.y = Double(Int(value))`

Comment: That´s because your `entry.y` is of type `Double`. What you can do is to remove the numbers after the decimal. I´ll update the answer.

Comment: How would I remove the numbers after the decimal?

Comment: Investigated this and even if you remove the numbers after the decimals you would still need to add Double value to `entry.y` my suggestion is to check the `DefaultValueFormatter` as MartinR gave example for to solve you issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let number = NSNumber(value: value)
entry.y = number.integerValue
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work. It makes me change it to `entry.y = Double(number.intValue)`